# Webpack: Undefined import during module evaluation

Tags: javascript, webpack, node-modules, es6-modules

I came across an issue I cannot solve. Imagine we have a module

```
export const Do = (arg) => arg + 1;
```

And another module

```
import { Do } from './Do';

const foo = 5;
export const DoneFoo = Do(foo);
```

When using webpack the emited code results in `Do is not a function` exception (as imported `Do` is `undefined`). However if I change the code to

```
import { Do } from './Do';

const foo = 5;
export const GetDoneFoo = () => Do(foo);
```

It works fine.
It seems that webpack orders modules in an order that evaluates the file before evaluating it's dependencies.

**This example is simplified. This problem occurs only in a single one large workspace** and only for certain modules. My hypothesis is that dependency graph is somewhat broken, however, I have no idea how to successfully debug it and fix the reason that causes the issue.

The bundle is outputted as a library and used within a web browser (window.libraryName).

Comment: Probably a cyclic dependency.

Comment: @JonasWilms The question is how to debug it efficiently?